# How to get string list index?

Tags: python

I have a list `text_lines = ['asdf','kibje','ABC','beea']` and I need to find an **index** where string `ABC`appears.

```
ABC = [s for s in text_lines if "ABC" in s]
```

`ABC` is now "ABC".
How to get index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Comment: nah, not a duplicate of that

Answer (score 4):

Greedy (raises exception if not found):

```
index = next(i for i, s in enumerate(text_lines) if "ABC" in s)
```

Or, collect all of them:

```
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(text_lines) if "ABC" in s]
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing: I would need to include `*ABC*`, so all occurances of ABC in any string would be reported (their indexes I ment). Possible?

Comment: `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` Any idea?

Comment: It needs to return `ABC` as substring too, sorry if I was not clear. So this  XYZABCXYZ would also be detected.

Comment: @Danijel the last one fails if you only have one "ABC" in your list

Comment: @Danijel fixed ValueError sorry

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the index of "ABC" ?

If there is just one "ABC", you can use built-in `index()` method of list:

```
text_lines.index("ABC")
```

Else, if there are more than one "ABC"s, you can use enumerate over the list:

```
indices = [idx for idx,val in enumerate(text_lines) if val == "ABC"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text_lines = ['asdf','kibje','ABC','beea']

abc_index = text_lines.index('ABC')
```

if 'ABC' appears only once. the above code works, because index gives the index of first occurrence.

for multiple occurrences you can check wim's answer

Comment: Thanks. I need to detect not identical strings, but substrings too, like `xABCyz`. Do you have solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Simple python list function.

```
index = text_lines.index("ABC")
```

If the string is more complicated, you may need to combine with regex, but for a perfect match this simple solution is best.